# ¿Alguien sabe cuando utilizar paréntesis al trabajar con operadores lógicos en python?

Tags: python

Por ejemplo, yo estaba haciendo un ejercicio que requeria el uso de operadores logicos(el operador "and" en este caso) y al principio no funcionaba del todo dicho código. Pero cuando utilice paréntesis en ciertos lugares, empezó a funcionar. Alguien me puede explicar cuando sería necesario el uso de estos paréntesis?

Les dejo el código para que entiendan mejor:

```
def max_de_tres(n1,n2,n3):
    if n1 > (n2 and n3):
        return n1
    elif n2 > (n1 and n3):
        return n2
    elif n3 > (n2 and n1):
        return n3
    else:
        print("Ninguno de los 3 numeros es mayor")

print(max_de_tres(11,20,250))
```

Comment: En Python, los paréntesis se utilizan para agrupar expresiones y establecer el orden de evaluación de las mismas. Por lo que depende de la expresion seran o no necesarios. Para que te hagas una idea que es el orden de evaluciaon, seria como resolver un acertijo y que para ello haya que resolver primero lo que esta entre parentesis...

Comment: ¿Tenés la certeza de que esos if están bien, aún teniendo paréntesis? ¿Acaso trataste de hacer algo similar a [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065407)?

Answer (score 1):

Los `if` son incorrectos. Podría ser algo así:

```
def max_de_tres(n1,n2,n3):
    if n1 > n2 and n1 > n3:
        return n1
    elif n2 > n1 and n2 > n3:
        return n2
    elif n3 > n2 and n3 > n1:
        return n3
    else:
        print("Ninguno de los 3 numeros es mayor")

print(max_de_tres(11,20,250))
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que tener en cuenta, como en las operaciones matemáticas, es el orden de evaluación (de derecha a izquierda) y la prioridad de los operadores. Tienes una tabla completa con dicho orden en la documentación oficial de Python:

https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

La necesidad o no de usar paréntesis para modificar el orden de evaluación de una expresión vendrá dada en cada caso por la lógica que necesitas aplicar para resolver tu problema concreto. Tampoco pasa nada por poner paréntesis explícitos cuando no es necesario estrictamente, en algunos casos mejoran la legibilidad del código.

En tu caso concreto:

```
if n1 > n2 and n3
```

El operador de comparación `>` tiene prioridad sobre el `and`, incluso teniendo la misma prioridad, se seguiría evaluando primero el `>` por estar mas a la izquierda. Al colocar el paréntesis en torno al `and`, fuerzas que se evalúe primero `n2 and n3` en vez de `n1 > n2`, y no es trivial:

```
4 > 7 and 3 -> False and 3 -> False
4 > (7 and 3) -> 4 > 3 -> True
```

Dicho esto, tienes un problema con la lógica, no de orden de evaluación y prioridad de operadores:

```
n1 and n2
```

donde `n1` y `n2` son números. El `and` evaluá la expresión a su izquierda primero, si es falsa la retorna, si es verdadera evalúa la expresión a su derecha y retorna el resultado. **Un entero es falso solo si es 0**, lo que se traduce en:

```
-7 and 4 -> 4
3 and -13 -> -13
8 and 1 -> 1
0 and 7 -> 0
7 and 0 -> 0
0 and 0 -> 0
```

ese `and` o retorna 0 o el numero de la derecha, lo que nos lleva a cosas como:

```
>>> max_de_tres(11, 0, 250)) 
11 # ?????????????????????????????

>>> max_de_tres(0, 8, 250)
8  # ?????????????????????????????
```

Moraleja, no intentes ahorrarte el segundo `>`, debes hacer algo como:

```
if n1 > n2 and n1 > n3
```

no necesitas paréntesis porque como dije antes `>` tiene preferencia, pero si quieres ser explicito, esto es lo mismo:

```
if (n1 > n2) and (n1 > n3):
```

Igual con los otros dos condicionales.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)